# To clarify my answer on finding out how much money is recieved by each person in a chain started by 6 people.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Q: A bond of letters starts with a person sending a letter out to 10 others. Each person is asked to send the letter out to 10 others, and each letter contains a list of the previous six people in the chain. Unless there are fewer than six names in the list, each person sends one dollar to the first person in this list, removes the name of this person from the list, moves up each of the other five names one position, and inserts his or her name at the end of this list. If no person breaks the chain and no one receives more than one letter, how much money will a person in the bond ultimately receive?

I tried solving it:

$6$ people will send the letter to $10$ different people (since we started the chain with $6$ people).
Now, in $2$nd round. the $1$st person name is removed, and new person is added. Therefore, $1$st person receives $1$.

Therefore, we can say total people in $2$nd round = $6*10 = 60$.Then, total money by $1$st person is $6$.

Now, in $3$rd round, we can say total will be $600$ people. So, the person who is now on top of everyone list is the 2nd person of 1st round. Therefore, he receives $600$$.

So, we can say each person of the 1st round will receive = $60+600+6000+60,000+600,000+6,000,000$ total dollars.

Comment: Please format the question using MathJax.

Comment: @UmeshShankar Check now.